# Where can I find a complete timeline of the history of Points of Light?

Tags: dnd-4e, lore, online-resources

A year or two ago whilst doing research for a D&D 4e campaign, I came across a *fantastic* timeline of the history of its default setting, Points of Light. The timeline tracked events including the Dawn War and the fall of Nerath with both years and manual and page citations. My Google-fu is now failing me in finding it, and it's possible it no longer exists, but it was very useful to have.

In light of that: where can I now find a complete compilation of Points of Light's history, complete with years and manual (and preferably page) citations?

Comment: Should I turn this from a "find me this thing I remember" question into a "find me a history of everything; I remember a thing like this exists" question?

Comment: This is an interesting example of how, despite WotC creating the setting specifically to not have anything nailed down, fans will still nail everything down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be remembering the timelines in the Points of Light Wiki. It's divided into pages based on the Ages ([Mythic Age](http://tahlequahpointsoflight.wikia.com/wiki/Mythic_Age), [Imperial Age](http://tahlequahpointsoflight.wikia.com/wiki/Imperial_Age), [Modern Age](http://tahlequahpointsoflight.wikia.com/wiki/Modern_Age)) and presents a detailed timeline of events loosely grouped into timeframes (such as "Fall of Nerath", or "The Dawn War"), while citing the sources for each entry, for instance (emphases mine):

> **CY-310**: Human settlers from Nerath move north into the Nentir Vale, establishing Fastormel, Harkenwold, and Winterhaven. Aranda Markelhay built the Moonstone Keep, around which Fallcrest began to grow. Valthrun’s Tower was possibly built around this time. **(DMG, p.198; KotS, p.20)**

Is this the resource you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

A fan-guide pdf for the history of Nentir Vale was produced by Zeromaru X. It covers history from The Age before ages, the Dawnwar, the rise and fall of the Nerith, and the current age. It also includes references to sourcebooks with page numbers.

It can be found here:
https://img.fireden.net/tg/image/1508/15/1508152617543.pdf